Android Kotlin Compose - How can I trigger flow every day when time on device is 00:00?
Android Kotlin Compose - How can I trigger flow every day when time on device is 00:00 ?
I've created Task Manager where I can create some tasks. Task has status CREATED, IN PROGRESS, DONE, FAILED. The task status should be change to FAILED when due date is less then current date in device.
Could you please advise how can I listen the date changing in order to automatically trigger flow that change status of task?

Please provide the code you have so far.

Use AlarmManager

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
